# Extending Html.BeginForm renders wrong url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following helpers:

```
public static MvcForm BeginFormEx(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)
{
  return htmlHelper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, new { environment = "test" }, method, htmlAttributes);
}

public static MvcForm BeginFormEx(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)
{
  if (routeValues == null)
  {
    return htmlHelper.BeginFormEx(actionName, controllerName, method, htmlAttributes);
  }

  routeValues["environment"] = "test";
  return htmlHelper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, method, htmlAttributes);
}

public static MvcForm BeginFormEx(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)
{
  if (routeValues == null)
  {
    return htmlHelper.BeginFormEx(actionName, controllerName, method, htmlAttributes);
  }

  return htmlHelper.BeginFormEx(actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), method, htmlAttributes);
}
```

I call it like:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormEx("myAction", "myController", new { returnUrl = ... }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
```

It renders form like:

```
<form action="/myController/myAction?Count=2&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D" method="post" role="form">
```

Why ?

I expected to get

```
<form action="/myController/myAction?returnUrl=...&environment=test" ... >
```

Why is not working ?

If use

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(.., ..., new { environment = "test" }, ....)
```

it works fine. Only if is called as extension is not working.

Also works fine if

```
@using (Html.BeginFormEx("myAction", "myController", null, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
```

Seems that not working the extending/adding new property to already existing routeValues. How to fix that ?

I made similar with `ActionLink` and it works fine, I mean that I see `environment` in query string.

Comment: The ActionLink in a controller parses the response body.  You have a request with parameters after the question mark in the URL.  The parameters are queries that return results.   Your two URLs have different parameters so you are getting two different type of response.  You controller has to be able to recognize more than one type of response.

Comment: What beginforn has to do with controller? is about form html rendering with unusual action url.

Comment: The begin form and the response have to be consistent.  If you have a form with 5 text boxes the response also need to contain the data to fill those textboxes.  So you would have to send a request with the right parameters to get a response with the data for the 5 textboxes.

Comment: What form and what response ? I'm asking about weird url rendering when use BeginFormEx which calls BeginForm ... why happens that ?

Comment: You have a form that is displaying the response from the server.  The URL is what is sent to server and the results in the response.  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4088a7/extending-mvc-ajax-form/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Ok, how to extend then the anonymous object to force add `environment` key every time when render form ? that I'm trying to do in above question.

Comment: And other strange situation: If I use `@using (Html.BeginFormEx("myAction", "myController", null, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))`, null for routeValues, seems that url is working by adding correct query string. So extending routeValues object cause the problem, don't know how to solve it

Comment: The "form action" contains a URL with parameters after the question mark.  The results is determine by "routeValues["environment"] = "test""  which checks the contents of the response and call the proper BeginForm.  You app could be expecting two different responses which can have two different routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```cs
return htmlHelper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, method, htmlAttributes);
```

calls the [`(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, FormMethod, Object)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_FormExtensions_BeginForm_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Web_Mvc_FormMethod_System_Object_), passing the `RouteValueDictionary routeValues` for `object routeValues`, which serializes the properties of the dictionary as if it was an anonymous object.

There isn't an overload of `BeginForm` that accepts `RouteValueDictionary routeValues` and `object htmlAttributes` at the same time. It's either `object`+`object` or `Dictionary`+`Dictionary`.

You can [make a dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes?view=aspnetcore-5.0) out of your `object htmlAttributes` to end up calling the [right overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_FormExtensions_BeginForm_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Web_Mvc_FormMethod_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__):

```cs
routeValues["environment"] = "test";
return htmlHelper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, method, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
```

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, combining parameter's type occur strange serialization. Thanks alot !